# Comparing multiple sample proportions between two groups where one group is a subset of the other

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, proportion, fishers-exact-test

I have 2 populations which I want to test if the proportions between group A and B are the same for each location or not by using hypothesis testing. It's very much as this problem described here: [Comparing multiple sample proportions between two groups](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/508734/comparing-multiple-sample-proportions-between-two-groups). However in my case it's not between two independent groups but group B population is a subset of group A's. Can I still use the method described in the link or do I have to think differently? Is there a fallacy I am missing out here? My data looks like this:

```
                           Group A    Group B
Location 1                 20090      17
Location 2                 24604      10
Location 3                 12284      5
Location 4                 14843      12
Location 5                 20592      9
Location 6                 8715       4
```

I am thinking because I have such a low count in group B, Fisher's exact test should be better suited here if I am gonna use something similar as the link.

Comment: If these are truly *populations* then just compare the proportions: they are whatever they are.  If they are *samples,* then just compare group $B$ to everything that's in $A$ but not in $B.$  The chi-squared test will work fine.

Comment: Please clarify what the proportions are in reference to...and to make sure I'm understanding the question, the last location has 4 B, 8715 A, and thus 8711 A-which-are-not-B...¿is this correct?

Comment: @GreggH yes that is correct.

Comment: And you are just asking if the distribution across locations is the same as for B as for A-not-B.  If so, this is just a multinomial comparison.

Comment: Yeah, after your input I realize I could do a Fischer exact test with simulated p-values in R. It would give me a p-value which meant I couldn't reject H_0